# Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I need to use react-native-scrollable-tab-view and accompanying that, I also installed/setup react-native-viewpager following this [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/master/README.md#mostly-automatic). This error suddenly appeared and currently, I still can't find a way to solve it. I hope someone encountered it already and help me. I just started working with React Native 1 wk ago but this project I've been working on have been existing for more than a year so not all dependencies are updated including react-native which version is 0.59.10. I've already tried using react-native-scrollable-tab-view with a sample project using latest version of react-native and it works fine but unfortunately I don't think I can upgrade this project cause there are just so many dependencies that will be affected that complicates things. I hope there is a way to resolve it without having to affect other dependencies. Here is the error part of the log:

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/sw
>   mansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
>                                 ^
>   /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/sw
>   mansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
>     private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool EVENTS_POOL =
>                               ^
>   /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
>                                 ^
>   /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
>     private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool EVENTS_POOL =
>                               ^
>   /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
>             new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
>                      ^
>   /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
>             new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
>                      ^
>   Note: /Users/markrogercabadsan/ReactNativeProjects/endless-aisle-hybrid/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 24s
251 actionable tasks: 27 executed, 224 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Marks-MacBook-Pro:endless-aisle-hybrid markrogercabadsan$

Comment: do you have linked your module using react-native link and builded through Android studio?

Comment: add your package.json file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is already solved. Also, Thanks [Mayank Pandav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4981359/mayank-pandav) for pointing that out. As you thought, I forgot to run `react-native link @react-native-community/viewpager` since auto-linking is not done on react native versions < 0.60. After linking, I still had some problem, the usual error with Nullable thingy in react native android but I was able to solve it by migrating to AndroidX thru following this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) and adding the following lines in my **gradle.properties** file:

> android.useAndroidX=true;
>
> android.enableJetifier=true;

And after re-running, the error is gone. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in the android folde, and it hsoould solve it:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the  react-native-gesture-handler version to 1.10.3